# What action triggers onItemSelected in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView of Medications that use a CursorAdapter. My goal is to obtain a reference to the Cursor of the selected item when the user presses the submit button, but I keep getting a null value. Here is my current code:

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Cursor selectedMedication = (Cursor) mMedicationListView.getSelectedItem();
        if(selectedMedication != null)
        {
            MedicationSelectionListener activity = (MedicationSelectionListener) getActivity();
            activity.onMedicationSelected(new Medication(selectedMedication));
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Must select a medication.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

When this executes, `selectedMedication` is always null. I have implemented a drawable selector.xml file that changes the background color of the item when it is pressed, and that works fine, so I was under the impression that clicking the item was enough.

I have also tried the following, by setting the selected medication variable each time an item is clicked:

```
mMedicationListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Cursor c = (Cursor) mMedicationListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
            mSelectedMedication = new Medication(c);
    }
});
```

This worked fine, but I felt it preformed a bunch of pointless operations when all I am interested in is the final selected item. Should clicking an item trigger `mMedicationListView.onItemSelected()`? If not, what action is used to ensure that happens?

Comment: What do you mean by "a bunch of pointless operations"?

Comment: @Emmanuel Let's say I have a large list medications, and for some reason the user selected up and down each and every one of them. Each time I'm changing that class field (which isn't a heavy operation, I get that) but why waste time doing that when I should be able to just read the selected item at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I was under the impression that clicking the item was enough.

Clicks are not selections with a `ListView`. A selection will occur either when:

- you set a selection programmatically, or
- the user uses a five-way navigation option (e.g., D-pad, trackball, arrow keys) and presses up/down on that to move a highlight bar around

> all I am interested in is the final selected item

A `ListView` is a command widget by default. When the user taps on a row in a `ListView`, your app should go do something, usually getting rid of the `ListView` along the way.

If, OTOH, the user is *choosing* something, where the list and choice remain on-screen (e.g., master-detail pattern, choosing a state/province as part of filling in an address), then you should be using a choice mode. That could be a single-choice mode (usually represented with radio buttons down the right edge), multiple-choice mode (usually represented with checkboxes down the right edge), or multiple-choice-modal mode (usually represented by an "activated" state setting a persistent highlight, usually reserved for master-detail sorts of scenarios).

Do **not** attempt to overload "selection" to mean "choice". It sounds like you are presenting a `ListView` as part of something larger, where the user is making a choice, so use a choice mode for that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference, I had no idea it was specific to the navigation options as you mentioned. The ListView is single choice already. Should I continue to handle this with the `onClick` approach then?

Comment: @McAdam331: If it is a single-choice list, you find out what the user chose via `getCheckedItemPosition()`, called on your `ListView`.